# Set PasswordNeverExpires flag for Local User Group through Powershell

Tags: powershell, passwords, local

I need to be able to change the PasswordNeverExpires option in the Local User Group properties area.

[image: User Properties Example]

I already know that I will have to use a flag in order to perform this action as stated in the article:

[How to use the UserAccountControl flags to manipulate user account properties](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144)

How would I be able to target the user in question through a Powershell script?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This will also work.

```
Set-LocalUser -Name "Administrator" -PasswordNeverExpires:$true
```

See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt651674.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

Here is a link with more information:

[[Win 7] setting the option "Password never expires" for a specific local user](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e4e96a5e-3b28-4673-8c61-d4abdf8f2426/win-7-setting-the-option-password-never-expires-for-a-specific-local-user?forum=winserverpowershell)

Basically, you'd create a script like so:

```
$user = [adsi]"WinNT://$env:computername/administrator"
$user.UserFlags.value = $user.UserFlags.value -bor 0x10000
$user.CommitChanges()
```

And then run it, making sure that you replace 'administrator' with the user in question.